Authentication issue with AWS SDK for PHP and EventBridge client
I have created global endpoint for EventBridge buses, one in us-east1, another in eu-north1 I use Wordpress instance hosted on AWS Lightsail to send event from PHP to global endpoint.
I installed composer and AWS SDK under PATH/vendor/.
AWS CRT extension istalled
My PHP function:
require_once(__DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php');

use Aws\EventBridge\EventBridgeClient;
use Aws\Credentials\Credentials;
use Aws\Signature\SignatureV4;

$credentials = new Credentials('YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID', 'YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY');

$evClient = new EventBridgeClient([
'region' => 'us-east-1',
'version' => 'latest',
'signature' => new SignatureV4('eventbridge', 'us-east-1'),
'credentials' => $credentials
]);


$endpointId = 'my-endpoint.veo';  
$eventBusName = 'my-bus-name';    

$event =  [
    'Source' => 'cybertechtalk',
    'DetailType' => 'test',
    'Detail' => json_encode(['foo' => 'bar']),
    'Time' => new DateTime(),
    'Resources' => ['php-script'],
    'EventBusName' => $eventBusName,
    'TraceHeader' => 'test'
];

$result = $evClient->putEvents([
    'EndpointId' => $endpointId,
    'Entries' => [$event]
]);

Exception:
Uncaught Aws\Auth\Exception\UnresolvedAuthSchemeException: This operation requests `sigv4a` auth schemes, but the client currently supports `sigv4`, `none`, `bearer`, `sigv4-s3express`. in /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/insert-headers-and-footers/includes/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/EndpointV2/EndpointV2Middleware.php:265

Stack trace:
#0 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/insert-headers-and-footers/includes/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/EndpointV2/EndpointV2Middleware.php(233): Aws\EndpointV2\EndpointV2Middleware->resolveAuthScheme()
#1 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/insert-headers-and-footers/includes/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/EndpointV2/EndpointV2Middleware.php(96): Aws\EndpointV2\EndpointV2Middleware->applyAuthScheme()
#2 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/insert-headers-and-footers/includes/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Middleware.php(90): Aws\EndpointV2\EndpointV2Middleware->__invoke()
#3 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/insert-headers-and-footers/includes/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/IdempotencyTokenMiddleware.php(77): Aws\Middleware::Aws\{closure}()
#4 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/insert-headers-and-footers/includes/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/AwsClientTrait.php(64): Aws\IdempotencyTokenMiddleware->__invoke()
#5 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/insert-headers-and-footers/includes/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/AwsClientTrait.php(58): Aws\AwsClient->executeAsync()
#6 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/insert-headers-and-footers/includes/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/AwsClientTrait.php(86): Aws\AwsClient->execute()
#7 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/insert-headers-and-footers/includes/class-wpcode-snippet-execute.php(287) : eval()'d code(25): Aws\AwsClient->__call()
#8 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/insert-headers-and-footers/includes/class-wpcode-snippet-execute.php(287): eval()
#9 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/insert-headers-and-footers/includes/execute/class-wpcode-snippet-execute-php.php(32): WPCode_Snippet_Execute->safe_execute_php()
#10 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/insert-headers-and-footers/includes/execute/class-wpcode-snippet-execute-type.php(55): WPCode_Snippet_Execute_PHP->prepare_snippet_output()
#11 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/insert-headers-and-footers/includes/class-wpcode-snippet.php(623): WPCode_Snippet_Execute_Type->get_output()
#12 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/insert-headers-and-footers/includes/class-wpcode-snippet.php(465): WPCode_Snippet->run_activation_checks()
#13 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/insert-headers-and-footers/includes/admin/pages/class-wpcode-admin-page-snippet-manager.php(1087): WPCode_Snippet->save()
#14 /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): WPCode_Admin_Page_Snippet_Manager->submit_listener()
#15 /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#16 /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action()
#17 /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php(175): do_action() #18 {main} thrown

I installed composer and AWS SDK under PATH/vendor/.
AWS CRT extension istalled
I tried to setup SignatureV4 implicite
